# Replacing @helper with taghelper when moving to asp.net core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In a current version of my application framework, I have a Razor HTML `@helper` that looks as follows:

```
@helper SideMenuItem(string display, string action, string controller, string area, string faIcon)
{
    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller, action)">
        <a href="@Url.Action(action, controller, new {area})"><i class="fa @faIcon"></i> <span class="nav-label">@display</span> </a>
    </li>
}
```

From what I can tell, this syntax format has been removed in asp.net core and the preferred method is now through [tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1). However, I'm struggling to understand what the equivalent in asp.net core would be. It seems bizarre that I'd need to now declare an entire class to get the same level of reuse that I got in the old `@helper` class. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but unfortunately no answer shows how to use a Tag Helper, which is the replacement for the @helper functions.

Comment: I added a new answer to show this

Comment: Thanks, @CamiloTerevinto, that's very helpful but also disappointing. It's unfortunate that the 'new' way requires so much more code and infrastructure. Its basically easier just to create markup manually